# How to Use UBound to Split Strings in a Column and Put the Separated Strings to Another Column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column (say, column D) of phone numbers, some of which have semicolon (;), or colon (,) to separate two phone numbers.
I would like to split the two phone numbers, and put the second one to a column to the left (say, column B), leave the first one in the original D column cell.  If there is only one phone number in the cell, then leave it alone.
I understand it probably will use UBound, and Split Array?  But how?
Can somebody help me please?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use cell formulae? `find`, `left`, `right` and `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely certain that their can only be two phone numbers in the cell, this should do the trick, or atleast it does for me:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim chkRng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim arr As Variant

Set chkRng = Range("D1:D" & (Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row))

For Each cell In chkRng

    If InStr(1, cell.Value, ",") > 0 Then

        arr = Split(cell.Value, ",")

    ElseIf InStr(1, cell.Value, ";") > 0 Then

        arr = Split(cell.Value, ";")

    Else
        GoTo continue

    End If

    cell.Offset(, -2).Value = Trim(arr(1))
    cell.Value = Trim(arr(0))

continue:
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub rep()

For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D65").Cells ' Change the range that you want

    If InStr(c.Value, ",") > 0 Then

        phonNumb = Split(c, ",")
        Range("D" & c.Row) = phonNumb(0)
        Range("C" & c.Row) = phonNumb(1)

    ElseIf InStr(c.Value, ";") > 0 Then

        phonNumb = Split(c, ";")
        Range("D" & c.Row) = phonNumb(0)
        Range("C" & c.Row) = phonNumb(1)
    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it works.  But I think the two Ifs can be merged with an ElseIf?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a much more simple way to do this but you could use an `Instr` function to locate the semicolons (;) or commas (,) and then separate them that way. For example the following works:

```
Sub SeparateNumbers()

Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D" & ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each Cell In Rng
    If InStr(1, Cell.Value, ";") Then
        Cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = Trim(Mid(Cell.Value, InStr(1, Cell.Value, ";") + 1, (Len(Cell.Value) - (InStr(1, Cell.Value, ";")))))
        Cell.Value = Mid(Cell.Value, 1, InStr(1, Cell.Value, ";") - 1)
    End If
    If InStr(1, Cell.Value, ",") Then
        Cell.Offset(0, -2).Value = Trim(Mid(Cell.Value, InStr(1, Cell.Value, ",") + 1, (Len(Cell.Value) - (InStr(1, Cell.Value, ",")))))
        Cell.Value = Mid(Cell.Value, 1, InStr(1, Cell.Value, ",") - 1)
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```